# Pyinstaller create non-working executable file (ImportError)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller

I created exe (one-file mode) by pyinstaller on PC with Win7 and it works OK. I have trouble with launching executable file on another PC with Win8.1. Program launches, but in some part of program I receive ImportError. Execubtable file used path with lib from my PC-Win7. How to correctly add pandas to exe and resolve problem? Thanks in advance.

I found analagous solved problem 
[Pyinstaller ImportError with scipy: DLL load failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096010/pyinstaller-importerror-with-scipy-dll-load-failed), but didn't understand how it apply to my problem.

Pyinstaller created warn.txt in build-folder contains about pandas (and about pandas.core.window, in particular):

```
missing module named pandas.factorize - imported by pandas (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.util.hashing (delayed, conditional)
missing module named pandas.unique - imported by pandas (delayed), pandas.core.arrays.base (delayed)
missing module named pandas.option_context - imported by pandas (top-level), pandas.io.clipboards (top-level)
missing module named pandas.NaT - imported by pandas (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level)
missing module named pandas.Period - imported by pandas (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level)
missing module named pandas.SparseDataFrame - imported by pandas (top-level), pandas.io.pytables (top-level)
missing module named pandas.SparseSeries - imported by pandas (top-level), pandas.io.pytables (top-level)
missing module named pandas.Int64Index - imported by pandas (top-level), pandas.io.feather_format (top-level), pandas.io.parquet (top-level), pandas.io.pytables (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.core.dtypes.concat (delayed), pandas.core.algorithms (delayed)
missing module named pandas.RangeIndex - imported by pandas (top-level), pandas.io.feather_format (top-level), pandas.io.parquet (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.core.dtypes.concat (delayed), pandas.util.testing (top-level)
missing module named pandas.Interval - imported by pandas (top-level), pandas.core.reshape.tile (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level)
missing module named pandas.Timedelta - imported by pandas (top-level), pandas.core.reshape.tile (top-level), pandas.core.reshape.merge (top-level)
missing module named pandas.Categorical - imported by pandas (top-level), pandas.core.reshape.tile (top-level), pandas.core.reshape.merge (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.core.dtypes.concat (delayed), pandas.core.dtypes.cast (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.util.hashing (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.dtypes.common (delayed, conditional), pandas.util.testing (top-level)
missing module named pandas.concat - imported by pandas (delayed), **pandas.core.window (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.groupby.groupby (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.sparse.frame (delayed), pandas.io.pytables (top-level), pandas.core.strings (delayed)**
missing module named pandas.isna - imported by pandas (top-level), pandas.io.json.json (top-level), pandas.io.stata (top-level), pandas.io.pytables (top-level)
missing module named pandas.CategoricalIndex - imported by pandas (delayed), pandas.core.arrays.categorical (delayed), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.core.dtypes.concat (delayed), pandas.util.testing (top-level)
missing module named pandas.Float64Index - imported by pandas (delayed), pandas.core.internals (delayed), pandas.io.packers (top-level)
missing module named pandas.Timestamp - imported by pandas (delayed), pandas.core.indexes.timedeltas (delayed), pandas.core.reshape.tile (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level)
missing module named pandas.DateOffset - imported by pandas (delayed), pandas.core.indexes.datetimelike (delayed)
missing module named pandas.Panel - imported by pandas (delayed), pandas.core.indexing (delayed), pandas.io.pytables (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.util.testing (top-level)
missing module named pandas.MultiIndex - imported by pandas (top-level), pandas.core.reshape.concat (top-level), pandas.io.json.json (top-level), pandas.core.window (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.reshape.merge (top-level), pandas.io.formats.excel (top-level), pandas.core.reshape.pivot (delayed, conditional), pandas.io.pytables (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.core.strings (delayed), pandas.core.util.hashing (delayed), pandas.util.testing (top-level)**
missing module named pandas.DataFrame - imported by pandas (delayed), pandas.core.accessor (delayed), pandas.core.reshape.concat (top-level), pandas.core.indexing (delayed), pandas.core.indexes.timedeltas (delayed), pandas.io.json.json (top-level), pandas.plotting._tools (delayed), pandas.plotting._core (delayed), pandas.core.indexes.multi (delayed), pandas.core.window (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.reshape.merge (top-level), pandas.io.feather_format (top-level), pandas.io.parquet (top-level), pandas.core.reshape.pivot (delayed), pandas.io.json.normalize (top-level), pandas.io.json.table_schema (top-level), pandas.io.pytables (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.io.clipboards (top-level), pandas.core.generic (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.strings (delayed), pandas.core.indexes.base (delayed), pandas.core.base (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.tools.datetimes (delayed), pandas.util.testing (top-level)
missing module named pandas.Index - imported by pandas (delayed), pandas.core.algorithms (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.accessor (delayed), pandas.core.reshape.concat (top-level), pandas.core.indexes.datetimelike (delayed), pandas.core.arrays.categorical (delayed), pandas.compat.pickle_compat (top-level), pandas.core.window (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.reshape.merge (top-level), pandas.io.formats.excel (top-level), pandas.io.pytables (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.core.strings (delayed), pandas.core.base (delayed), pandas.core.dtypes.concat (delayed), pandas.core.sorting (delayed), pandas.core.tools.datetimes (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.util.hashing (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.dtypes.dtypes (delayed), pandas.util.testing (top-level)
missing module named pandas.PeriodIndex - imported by pandas (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.algorithms (delayed, conditional), pandas.io.formats.excel (top-level), pandas.io.pytables (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.util.testing (top-level)
missing module named pandas.DatetimeIndex - imported by pandas (delayed, optional), pandas.core.dtypes.cast (delayed, conditional, optional), pandas.core.algorithms (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.missing (delayed, optional), pandas.core.indexes.datetimelike (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.indexes.timedeltas (delayed), pandas.io.stata (top-level), pandas.io.pytables (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.core.tools.datetimes (delayed), pandas.util.testing (top-level)
missing module named pandas.to_numeric - imported by pandas (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.dtypes.cast (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.arrays.categorical (delayed), pandas.core.tools.datetimes (delayed)
missing module named pandas.to_timedelta - imported by pandas (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.dtypes.cast (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.arrays.categorical (delayed), pandas.core.window (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.groupby.groupby (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.reshape.tile (top-level), pandas.io.stata (top-level), pandas.core.tools.datetimes (delayed)
missing module named pandas.TimedeltaIndex - imported by pandas (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.tools.timedeltas (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.algorithms (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.indexes.datetimes (delayed), pandas.io.pytables (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.util.testing (top-level)
missing module named pandas.to_datetime - imported by pandas (delayed, conditional, optional), pandas.core.dtypes.cast (delayed, conditional, optional), pandas.core.arrays.categorical (delayed), pandas.io.json.json (top-level), pandas.core.groupby.groupby (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.reshape.tile (top-level), pandas.io.stata (top-level), pandas.io.pytables (top-level), pandas.core.generic (delayed, conditional)
missing module named pandas.Series - imported by pandas (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.dtypes.missing (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.tools.timedeltas (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.algorithms (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.missing (delayed), pandas.core.accessor (delayed), pandas.core.reshape.concat (top-level), pandas.core.indexing (delayed), pandas.io.formats.format (delayed), pandas.core.indexes.datetimes (delayed), pandas.core.arrays.categorical (delayed), pandas.io.json.json (top-level), pandas.plotting._core (delayed), pandas.core.indexes.multi (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.window (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.reshape.tile (top-level), pandas.core.apply (delayed, conditional), pandas.io.pytables (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.core.generic (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.indexes.accessors (delayed), pandas.core.strings (delayed), pandas.core.indexes.base (delayed), pandas.core.base (delayed, conditional, optional), pandas.core.dtypes.concat (delayed), pandas.core.tools.datetimes (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.util.hashing (delayed), pandas.io.html (top-level), pandas.util.testing (top-level)
missing module named pandas.IntervalIndex - imported by pandas (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.dtypes.missing (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.indexes.category (delayed, conditional), pandas.core.reshape.tile (top-level), pandas.io.packers (top-level), pandas.util.testing (top-level)
missing module named pandas.get_option - imported by pandas (delayed), pandas.io.formats.console (delayed), pandas.io.parquet (top-level), pandas.io.clipboards (top-level)
```

My spec-file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['Main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Atlant\\Desktop\\myprog'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='MyProg',
          debug=True,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True, icon='icon.ico')
```

Tablet-PC with Win8.1 used incorrect paths (D:\Python\lib...) from my PC with Win7:
[image]

I need to be able to launch executable file on any PC with Windows 7 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

I had updated pandas and pyinstaller.

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
pip install pyinstaller --upgrade
```